# Converting string m/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS to date dd-mm-yyyy in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a string that looks like '1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM' and I want to reformat it to dd-mm-yyyy. 
Keep in mind that the month can be double digit sometimes.

Comment: use https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libraries like moment.js. Assuming either you do not want to use any external library or can not use it, then you can use following custom method:

```
function formatDate(dateStr) {
    let date = new Date(dateStr);
    let day = date.getDate();
    let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date.getFullYear();

    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}

console.log(formatDate('1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethink like this :

```
 var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    console.log(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
```

However best way is with Moment.js,where you can Parse, Validate, Manipulate, and Display dates in JavaScript.

example:

```
  var date= moment("06/06/2015 11:11:11").format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
```

Comment: I am trying the moment.js but still I get 'Thu Jan 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100' after conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertDate(oldDate) {
  var myDate = new Date(Date.parse(oldDate)); //String -> Timestamp -> Date object
  var day = myDate.getDate(); //get day
  var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1; //get month
  var year = myDate.getFullYear(); //get Year (4 digits)
  return pad(day,2) + "-" + pad(month, 2) + "-" + year; //pad is a function for adding leading zeros
}

function pad(num, size) { //function for adding leading zeros
  var s = num + "";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}

convertDate("1/11/2018 12:00:00 AM"); //11-01-2018
```

[Demo here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/03bn3vzg/10/)